# java stream for hashmap

Tags: java, pdf, hashmap, java-stream

I am building a `Hashmap<Integer, POJO>` from database (that can contains more than 10K records). Then I need to call a pdf generation function under traversal of hashmap

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, LocationPojo> village : allVillages.entrySet()) {

                genPdf(stateCode, village.getValue().getDistrictCode().toString() , village.getValue().getBlockCode().toString(), 
                        village.getValue().getVillageCode().toString(), village.getValue().getVillageNameEnglish(), villageFile);

        }
```

Is it possible to use `java 8 stream api`  for faster processing of above data ?

Comment: Stream API is not meant to process it faster. If the data in the stream can be processed alone, then it can be parallelized. If you need all the data in the Map to generate your pdf, then you cannot split it in several tasks.

Comment: Completely non-Stream related suggestion to your code: you can pass ```village``` into ```genPdf()```, then get out the Strings you need inside that method implementation, as opposed to passing so many arguments directly from the calling code.

Comment: Instead of `for(Map.Entry<Integer, LocationPojo> village : allVillages.entrySet()) …` you could have used `for(LocationPojo pojo: allVillages.values()) …` in the first place. Pick the right collection view for your task. There are `keySet()`, `entrySet()`, and `values()`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a stream to parallelize the `genPdf` calls:

```
allVillages.values().stream().parallel().forEach(village -> {
    genPdf(stateCode, village.getDistrictCode().toString(), village.getBlockCode().toString(),
            village.getVillageCode().toString(), village.getVillageNameEnglish(), villageFile);
});
```

Whether this actually speeds up processing depends on how much of `genPdf` can be run in parallel. A disk drive can only write one thing at a time, so if `genPdf` spends most of its time writing a PDF file to disk, you won't see much difference. Also keep in mind that this may change the order in which the villages are processed.

Comment: As I know, parallel() method implements multithreading internally so I personally prefer to using stream method. I considered faster processing of data with stream method. Thanks